# bt - Flexible Backtesting for Python - how to get total portfolio value/result for each given date?

Tags: python, pandas, portfolio, back-testing, bt

I have recently started using bt for backtesting, and after looking into the documentation, https://pmorissette.github.io/bt/bt.html, there does not seem to be a way to get the total portfolio value at each date, even though it can be easily plotted by calling the `.plot()` method.

I may have overlooked on my part since I am pretty new to this. Great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The library bt has various useful methods that you could use in your backtesting:

Then, assuming that `res = bt.run(backtest)`

You can do:
`res.prices` will tell you in a percentage format how your portfolio value is changing
`res.backtest_list[0].strategy.outlays` will tell you the outlays, which are the total dollar amount spent(gained) by a purchase(sale) of securities
`res.backtest_list[0].positions` will tell you the number of shares purchased
`res.get_security_weights()` will tell you the weight of your security in a percentage format